# Induction proof for inequality

Tags: real-analysis, induction

## The Problem

Prove that $P_n$ implies $P_{n+1}$ for:
$$\frac{1}{n!}\gt \frac{8^n}{(2n)!}$$

---

### My Attempt

Assume $P_n$ is true.
Check for $n+1$:

$$\frac{1}{(n+1)!} = \frac{1}{n!}\frac{1}{n+1}$$
and from $P_n$:
$$\frac{1}{n!}\frac{1}{n+1} \gt \frac{8^n}{(2n)!}\frac{1}{n+1} $$

---

### The question

How do I go further with this? How do I prove that the inequality actually holds? All guidelines will be much appreciated.

Comment: The problem does NOT ask you to prove the statement is true so there is no need to show that $P_O$ is true.  The problem only asks you to prove "if $P_n$ is true then $P_{n+1}$ is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, if $P_n$ is
$$ \tag{$P_n$}
\frac{1}{n!} > \frac{8^n}{(2n)!}
$$
then $P_{n+1}$ is
$$ \tag{$P_{n+1}$}
\frac{1}{(n+1)!} > \frac{8^{n+1}}{(2(n+1))!}
$$

You noted correctly that LHS is
$$
\frac{1}{(n+1)!} = \frac1{n+1} \times \frac1{n!}
$$
and the RHS is
$$
\frac{8^{n+1}}{(2(n+1))!}
 = \frac{8^{n+1}}{(2n+2)!}
 = \frac{8^n}{(2n)!} \times \frac{8}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}
$$

So using the Inductive Hypothesis, you have
$$
\frac{1}{(n+1)!}
 = \frac1{n+1} \times \frac1{n!}
 > \frac1{n+1} \times \frac{8^n}{(2n)!}
$$
and it suffices to prove that
$$
\frac1{n+1} > \frac{8}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}
$$
Can you now finish this?

Comment: Ah! I see. Sorry for my stupidity. Then I can show that $$\frac{1}{n+1} \gt \frac{8}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}$$, and the proof will be complete?

\\
EDIT: You added this to your answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Sonofgreek yes, correct :) nothing to be sorry about

Comment: After proving my last comment, I concluded that $$\frac{2n-3}{(n+1)(2n+1)} \gt 0$$ for all $n \ge 2$. Is this correct? And even though this applies for only $n \ge 2$ can one still say that $P_n$ implies $P_{n+1}$?

Comment: @Sonofgreek you have to manually verifty $n=1$ and $n=0$ if you want it

Answer (score 0):

Try to find when

$$\frac{8^n}{(2n)!}\cdot\frac{1}{n+1} > \frac{8^{n+1}}{(2(n+1))!} = \frac{8^n}{(2n)!}\cdot\frac{8}{2(n+1)(2n+1)}$$